# Issue with using Google.Apis Client on C#

Tags: c#, google-api, gtk#, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I'm using GTK# for my project. In application, when I press button and that triggers OnButton1Clicked functions, It crashes. Below is the code.

```
protected void OnButton1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serviceAccountEmail = "--------@api-project---------.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"serviceAccountKey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate)
        );
    }
```

And this is error msg.

```
Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential' from assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices, Version=1.9.3.19383, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
```

I have included Google.Apis package, and its fully updated.[image]

There was no packages anything, I've just add Google.Apis and everything installed due to dependencies.
I'm using Xamarin Studio and MacOSX.
Someone know what's causing this problem?

Comment: are the required dependencies properly referenced? The error indicates one of the types in the dependency graph couldn't be loaded.

Comment: you probably need to add Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 , and maybe Google.Apis.Services as well.  I normally just use the nugget packages